# ctypes user input to stream to another program

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I've made up this code, but as you can see at the end, it isn't ideal to do this with every key:

```
if (ThatKey == "e"): 
    ThatKey = E_KEY
```

Is there a more efficiënt way to do this?

(full code):
https://pastebin.com/ctnYVjxN

Comment: One thing: I havent made up the code I found the code and made some changes my self

Comment: Cant I use this in something like a function?

Answer (score 0):

The question itself has nothing to do with *ctypes* (the fact that it's used in the code it's irrelevant), so I removed the tag.

AFAIK there's no mapping between a *Virtual-Key Code* and its key name (if you will). Let's consider `VK_RETURN`. *Enter* key has lots of names:

- *Enter*, *Return*, *CR*, *\n*, *Carriage Return*, *0x0D*, ...
- The above are only the capitalized versions
- Localized versions

It would make no sense to have such a mapping, because there would always be changes required. So anyone who needs the mapping, will have to write it "manually".

*code.py*:

```
import sys


VK_TAB  = 0x09
VK_MENU = 0x12
VK_RETURN = 0x0D
VK_F1 = 0x70
VK_ESCAPE = 0x1B
# Some other VK_* keys

INVALID_VK = 0

SPECIAL_KEYS = {
    "ENTER": VK_RETURN,
    "ESC": VK_ESCAPE
}

def get_virtual_key_code(key_name, module=None, special_keys_mapping=None):
    key_name_upper = key_name.upper()
    if key_name.isalnum() and len(key_name) == 1:
        return ord(key_name_upper)
    vk_code_name = "VK_" + key_name_upper
    if module is None:
        vk_code = globals().get(vk_code_name, INVALID_VK)
    else:
        vk_code = getattr(module, vk_code_name, INVALID_VK)
    if vk_code == INVALID_VK and special_keys_mapping:
        vk_code = special_keys_mapping.get(key_name_upper, INVALID_VK)
    return vk_code


def main():
    vkc = None
    while vkc != VK_ESCAPE:
        key_name = raw_input("What key would you like to press: ")
        vkc = get_virtual_key_code(key_name, special_keys_mapping=SPECIAL_KEYS)
        print("Virtual key code for '{:s}': 0x{:02X}".format(key_name, vkc))
    print("Done.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} on {:s}\n".format(sys.version, sys.platform))
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- `get_virtual_key_code`:

  - `key_name`: it's the key's string representation
  - `module`: the module where the *VK_** constants are defined. Now. they're in the global section of the current module. But if you decide to move them into a separate module (which I'd recommend, to keep things modular), just pass it as an argument (after importing it, of course). Also, you could get rid of the 2<sup>nd</sup> `if` from the function (only keep the right branch)
  - If `key_name` is one of the alphanumeric chars, then its virtual code is the *ASCII* code (uppercase for letters). So, there's no need to define the corresponding *VK_** constants (or any other constants, like `E_KEY`)
  - Then, a constant name is constructed based on the key name (e.g. for ***f1*** key, the constant name will be `VK_F1`)
  - If a constant wasn't found, a special mapping (`special_keys_mapping` - if provided) is searched. This is for special cases (e.g. ***ENTER*** - `VK_RETURN` as there's no automated way to link them)
  - If no constant is found, ***0*** is returned
  - Every string comparison is case insensitive
- Code keeps running, til user wants to handle `VK_ESCAPE`
- It should also work in *Python3* (if replacing `raw_input` by `input`)

**Output**:

> ```
> (py27x64_test) e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q050638652>"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py27x64_test\Scripts\python.exe" code.py
> Python 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
>
> What key would you like to press: 1
> Virtual key code for '1': 0x31
> What key would you like to press: a
> Virtual key code for 'a': 0x41
> What key would you like to press: A
> Virtual key code for 'A': 0x41
> What key would you like to press:
> Virtual key code for ' ': 0x00
> What key would you like to press: f1
> Virtual key code for 'f1': 0x70
> What key would you like to press: f2
> Virtual key code for 'f2': 0x00
> What key would you like to press: return
> Virtual key code for 'return': 0x0D
> What key would you like to press: Enter
> Virtual key code for 'Enter': 0x0D
> What key would you like to press: ESC
> Virtual key code for 'ESC': 0x1B
> Done.
> ```